# Timezone: Mysql save UTC and PHP read America/Sao_Paulo

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I would like to save at mysql in UTC timezone and read with PHP using America/Sao_Paulo timezone.

Im using YII framework.
Its not working property, how could I do that?

main.php:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',

'db'=>array(
...
    'initSQLs'=>array("SET time_zone = '+00:00'"),
...
)
```

Comment: What do the fields look like? Are you saving timestamps or something else?

Comment: With this config the fields are returning in UTC, not in right timezone.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way, but it's impossible to give specific advice without more information. Even if the code was working fine this would not be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this in your PHP code:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Now PHP operates in UTC. It's up to you to convert to user local times but you have a common ground.

**And in MySQL** use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` for your `DATETIME` needs. It uses UTC time regardless of the MySQL settings so you don't need to worry anymore.

Comment: You can place this line of code in the index.php file of your application or in the config

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your mysql console or gui:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Then use again:

```
SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';
```

You also can change by this:

```
SET time_zone = 'Brazil/West';
```

Source: http://blog.will.eti.br/2013/mysql-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone-americasao_paulo/